# Struggle with obtaining same answer for both Disk-Washer Method and Shell Method on same Problem

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

The problem is straightforward with the Disk-Washer method.  To help me fully understand these rotation problems I like to work the problems using both Disk-Washer and Shell (some problems become too difficult to solve for the x or y variable, but most work at the Calculus 1 level).

The problem is:  Find the volume of the solid that results when the region is rotated about the **y-axis**.

$y=3-2x, y=2, y=0, x=0$

Using $V=\pi \int_{0}^2 (\frac{3-y}{2})^2 dy$ I get the correct answer of $13\pi/6$

When evaluating how to do this via the Shell method I notice that I will need to break this region into 2 pieces - a rectangle and a triangle.

Since the line $y=2$ intersects the line $y=3-2x$ at $(\frac{1}{2},2)$ I chose the two shell integrals as follows:

$V=2 \pi\int_{0}^\frac{1}{2} (x)(2) dx + 2\pi\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}} (x-\frac{1}{2})(3-2x)dx $

This does NOT produce the same answer. I think the correct answer is produced if I use:

$2\pi\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}} (x)(3-2x)dx $ for the second integral.  But I don't understand this.  For my second integral, it would seem to me that my radius is **NOT** $x$ but $(x-\frac{1}{2})$.

Can you assist with doing this problem via the Shell Method?

Comment: Distance of shells from the axis of rotation is $x$. It is the volume of shells by rotation is what you are adding. You split the integral into two only because the height of shell changes at $x = 0.5$. Look at it this way - if it was one integral, you would have used $x \ dx$ or not? Same thing but two integral as the shell height changes.

Comment: OK, I see that now.  It was the height that was changing not the radius.  Thank you tremendously for taking the time to answer!!!  People like you help others in many, many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second integral, the cylinder radius should be $x$, not $x-\tfrac{1}{2}$, as it is the distance of the position of the cylindrical shell from the rotation axis: the line $x=0$, not the line $x=\tfrac{1}{2}$.  With integrand $x(3-2x)$, you obtain the result $\frac{13\pi}{6}$ as with disks.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer!